# ParseTweets function for more than one JSON file at the same time using R

Tags: json, r

I have 100 JSON files contain approximately 800,000 tweets. How can I parse all files at the same time using R in order to clean it?

Comment: Where's your code?  Please see [Ask].  You also didn't even bother to take the 2-minute site [tour].

Comment: This is my code for one file, but I am asking about how to parse multiple files at the same time 
tweets <- parseTweets("C:\\Users\\Mohammed\\Documents\\testtweets\\tweetnew")

Comment: `lapply` across a vector of filenames (which you can probably create with `list.files`).

Comment: Also see [Gregor's excellent canonical answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/4497050).